# Does web browser treat css/js/img different from text

Tags: http, google-chrome, caching, browser

I have a webpage and in it some images etc. I clear my cache and hit the URL. The page request has the following response headers:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 21 Nov 2012 07:14:35 GMT
Etag:"1353481170-1"
Expires:Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 21 Nov 2012 06:59:30 +0000
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Vary:Cookie,Accept-Encoding
```

And one of the images has these response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:none
Cache-Control:max-age=1209600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:2206
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 21 Nov 2012 07:14:36 GMT
ETag:"6c4f9-89e-4cee5893ab000"
Expires:Wed, 05 Dec 2012 07:14:36 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 20 Nov 2012 04:19:12 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

When I hit the same URL again and see the console in chrome I see that for the main request my browser sends a If-modified-since and gets a prompt 304 from the server whereas for the image the browser does not send out a request and serves from the cache.

My questions are following:

1. Does the browser treat css/JS/img differently from text coz if you see the first response for both the resources had a max-age as well as last-modified header although the number of secs were different. Then how come for one it still sent a request and not for the other.
2. In case we have max-age as well as last-modified header which takes precedence ? The purpose of max-age (AFAIK) is that we save the round trip to the server and as per HTTP if a cache gets a last-modified header it will always send a if-modified-since in the subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, the browser shouldn't treat the files differently. It should just obey what the headers say. The browser doesn't send a new request for the image because the file it received hasn't yet expired.  Both the max-age and Expires headers specify that the doesn't expire for 2 weeks.
2. I don't think the `Last-Modified` header is relevant; age is calculated as the time since the object was sent (as specified in the `Date` header), not when it was modified.

A better question is which takes precedence between the `max-age` cache-control directive and the `Expires` header. RFC 2616 section 14.9.3 says:

> If a response includes both an Expires header and a max-age directive, the max-age directive overrides the Expires header, even if the Expires header is more restrictive.

Once an object has expired, the `Last-Modified` time will be used in the `If-Modified-Since`  header of the request.

Comment: Then why does it send a request for the main page when the max-age for it is 600 secs(10 mins) ?

Comment: I assumed it was because it's been more than 10 minutes since it cached the page.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not the case :( , thats Y I was wondering. May be the browsers always send a request for the main URL irrespective of the headers. Coz I have never seen any base URL being cached at the browser level the way it clearly caches the static content, but I might be wrong here.